# Removing rich text formatting for copy + paste? (Cross Browser)

Tags: javascript, html, css, aspdotnetstorefront

I'm not sure whether a Javascript or CSS fix could fix this issue on my site. This seems to only happen with Chrome (not sure about IE, yet).

Whenever a user copies text from my AspDotNetStorefront site and paste it onto a Word document, the pasted text includes a gray background. Is there anything I can do on my site to prevent this rich text formatting paste feature onto documents?

I'm not sure what would be the cause of this besides Microsoft Word's default paste setting.

Comment: typically, right-click "paste as plain text", or [ctrl]+[shift]+[V] does that. you can also convert to plain text by pasting then cutting in notepad first.

Comment: Thanks :) But I was trying to figure out a way where the user wouldn't have to do any of that stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.unselectable{
   position:absolute;
   z-index:1;
   color:green;
   -webkit-user-select:none;
}
.selectable{
   position:absolute;
   z-index:2;
   color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
   -webkit-user-select:text;
}
```

```html
<p class="unselectable">Lorem</p>
<p class="selectable">Lorem</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept the copy event, get the selection without style, and put that into the clipboard.

```
document.addEventListener('copy', function(e) {
  const text_only = document.getSelection().toString();
  const clipdata = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;  
  clipdata.setData('text/plain', text_only);
  clipdata.setData('text/html', text_only);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the clippy library https://github.com/mojombo/clippy to add a copy to clipboard button. This can help remove the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Flash, you could try something like this to make it easy to copy the text without formatting:

CSS:

```
#box {background-color:gray; color:white;width:200px;height:400px;align:center;margin-left:50px;padding:30px}
#copy {position:fixed;top:15px;left:200px;text-decoration:underline}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="copy" onclick="selectable('p')">Click to select text</div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla lacinia eros et justo pulvinar pulvinar. Pellentesque nec nisl feugiat, cursus lorem sed, venenatis sem. Curabitur vitae commodo ante, a pellentesque ligula. Morbi sit amet tincidunt ipsum. Fusce rutrum massa at velit dignissim accumsan. Donec hendrerit lorem sed leo viverra, vel cursus sapien lobortis. Praesent quis ligula non justo rhoncus placerat eu non leo. Pellentesque vitae congue enim. Quisque eget turp</p></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
selectable=function(selector){
    var $elem=$(selector);
    innerHTML=$(selector).html()  ;
    $elem.hide();
    $elem.parent().append($('<textarea />').val(innerHTML).css({height:'400px'}));
    $('textarea').select();
};
```

The code isn't beautiful, it's just to demonstrate the concept.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/rXG2G/

Answer (score -1):

Your question has nothing to do with javascript, html or css.

Pasting text in Word keeps formatting by default. To paste without formatting the user need to right click on the Word document and do a `Paste Special...`.

Comment: Not necessarily. I'm trying to figure out a way where the user wouldn't have to go through those steps (I'm thinking about those users who wouldn't know how to paste special). I want to handle it on my side, whether I could use something like `::selection`

Comment: In that case you could use a copy to clipboard button like Pim suggested. And when the user clicks it, you can copy a version of the text without the formatting.