# user-select:none still part of copied Rich Text in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28025049/447503) to copy and paste hyperlinks from Chrome as plain text and it seems to work when I paste to notepad. However, regardless of `user-select: none;`, when I paste the same clipboard contents to Libreoffice Writer all text is pasted. This happens when a styled block is surrounded by selectable blocks.

```css
.unselectable {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  color: green;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.selectable {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  user-select: text;
  -webkit-user-select: text;
}
```

```html
xxx
<p style="user-select: none;">
  <a href="mailto:unselectable@b.org">unselectable</a>
</p>

<p>
  <a href="mailto:default@b.org">default</a>
</p>

<div>
  <p unselectable="on" class="unselectable">unselectable2</p>
  <p>zzz</p>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried to select from xxx to zzz and all I get here in the stackeditor is `xxx

default

zzz`

Comment: Quite a lot of [dupes](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22user-select%3A+none%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: @mplungjan what version of Chrome and what's your Rich Text editor?

Comment: newest Chrome and the editor was the one below here

Comment: This works as expected. Maybe an addon causing this? Try if from Incognito tab

Comment: @basin have you found a solution for this? Currently stumbled across the same issue

Comment: @tristndev No, I haven't.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a bug in Chrome.

A work around would be using `-web-kit`

```css
.parent :not(.selectable-all) {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.selectable-all {
  -webkit-user-select: all;
  -moz-user-select: all;
  -ms-user-select: all;
  user-select: all;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span>un-selectable</span>
  <div class="child selectable-all">
    Selectable
  </div>
</div>

<div class="child selectable-all">
  Selectable
</div>
```

I tried and it works fine. Try and let me know if it worked for you as well.

Here is a link for reference;[User-select: all inheritance not working in chrome 62](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46883622/user-select-all-inheritance-not-working-in-chrome-62)

Comment: `web-kit` with a hyphen?

Comment: well yeaaaaaaaaa

Comment: Can you please post the full html? If I surround the divs from that answer with xxx and zzz the workaround doesn't work

Comment: So you mean this does not work when the zzz and/or xxx comes before the un-selectables?

Comment: This doesn't do anything. Try moving the `un-selectable` between the two `Selectable`s and you can see that the `un-selectable` is still copied when both `Selectable`s are copied in one enclosing selection. It looks like only Firefox has superior multi-range copying abilities, which is a shame because Chrome is more widely used.